# Android FCM - onMessageReceived not called on background

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM. Notifications are working properly and onMessageReceived is called on Foreground, but when I receive a notification while the app is in background/killed that method is never called.

I'm using data messages as Firebase Documentation suggested but no succeed...

Answer (score 3):

FCM has 3 kind of notifications

**1. Notification messages**
   Json body will be only having `notification` tag
   FCM will automatically show notification in client app if app is in background. `onMessageReceived()` will be called both in foreground . In background, `onMessageReceived()` will not be called.

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Data messages**
   Json body will be only having `data` tag
   Developer have to show notification. onMessageRecieved will be called both in foreground as well as in background. The json should only have data tag in it

```
 {
      "message":{
        "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
        "data":{
          "Nick" : "Mario",
          "body" : "great match!",
          "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
        }
      }
    }
```

**3. Notification and data messages**

The json body will be having both `notification` and `data` tags. `onMessageReceived()` will be called only when app is in foreground. Notifications will be shown automatically shown if app is in background and onMessageReceived()  will not be called.

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

For more info please read https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: this is the notification I'm sending:

`
  payload = new JSONObject();
  notification = new JSONObject();
  
     notification.put("title", "Avisos");
     notification.put("text", "Nuevos avisos disponibles");

  payload.put("data", notification);
  payload.put("to", "/topics/avisos");
     payload.put("priority",10); `

Comment: So I must include a token?

Comment: If you are sending message to one, then you should use token

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you add like this service in 
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".services.fcm.FirebaseService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the notification I'm sending:

```
 payload = new JSONObject();
 notification = new JSONObject();

 notification.put("title", "Avisos");
 notification.put("text", "Nuevos avisos disponibles");

 payload.put("data", notification);
 payload.put("to", "/topics/avisos");
 payload.put("priority",10);
```

Comment: This should be in the question